# Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'

Tags: android, android-keystore

I'm getting this error when running (Shift+F10) a project in Android Studio.

**Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.**

> Failed to read key key_name from store "/home/hello/AndroidStudioProjects/project/extras/keystorefile.jks": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

But it generates release .apk file without a problem.

Comment: anybody know how yo fix it?

Answer (score 1):

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}

signingConfigs {
    releaseConfig {
        storeFile file("keystore.jks")
        storePassword "**"
        keyAlias "key name is here"
        keyPassword "**"
    }
```

Note :use this lines in app.gradle. make sure the line should be start from "releaseConfig" should not "debug" on " signingConfigs".and its working.